# How do I ignore characters using the python pty module?

Tags: python, pty

I want to write a command-line program that communicates with other interactive programs through a pseudo-terminal. In particular I want to be able to cause keystrokes received to *conditionally* be sent to the underlying process.  Let's say for an example that I would like to silently ignore any "e" characters that are sent.

I know that Python has a [`pty` module](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/pty.html) for working with pseudo-terminals and I have a basic version of my program working using it:

```
import os
import pty

def script_read(stdin):
    data = os.read(stdin, 1024)

    if data == b"e":
        return ... # What goes here?
    return data

pty.spawn(["bash"], script_read)
```

From experimenting, I know that returning an empty bytes object `b""` causes the `pty.spawn` implementation to think that the underlying file descriptor has reached the end of file and should no longer be read from, which causes the terminal to become totally unresponsive (I had to kill my terminal emulator!).

Answer (score 0):

For interactive use, the simplest way to do this is probably to just return a bytes object containing a single null byte: `b"\0"`.  The terminal emulator will not print anything for it and so it will look like that input is just completely ignored.

This probably isn't great for certain usages of pseudo-terminals.  In particular, if the content written to the pseudo-terminal is going to be written again by the attached program this would probably cause random null bytes to appear in the file.  Testing with `cat` as the attached program, the sequence `^@` is printed to the terminal whenever a null byte is sent to it.

So, YMMV.

A more proper solution would be to create a wrapper type that can masquerade as an empty string for the purposes of `os.write` but that would evaluate as "truthy" in a boolean context to not trigger the end of file conditional.  I did some experimenting with this and couldn't figure out what needs to be faked to make `os.write` fully accept the wrapper as a string type.  I'm unclear if it's even possible. :(

Here's my initial attempt at creating such a wrapper type:

```py
class EmptyBytes():
    def __init__(self):
        self.sliced = False

    def __class__(self):
        return type(b"")

    def __getitem__(self, _key):
        return b""
```